# 404 modal - Erro ao carregar o template no modalHtml

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal

Estou em um sistema que quando se clica na "lupa" é aberto uma modal com as informações de Histórico. Mas estou recebendo um erro que a página Html não está sendo encontrada. O gulp está correto, ao debugar consigo ver o endereço do path, mas está dando os seguintes erros (segue o código também):

```
MinhaFactory.recuperarHistorico(filtro) //filtro com os dados certo
    .then(function (response) {
    var config = {
        vm: {
            listaHistorico: response.data.historico //está retornando os dados corretamente
        },
        size: "xl",
        header: "Meu Titulo",
        html: "/app/modulos/minha-pasta/view/historico.html"
    };

    modalService.exibirModalHtml(config);
})
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);

        modalService.exibirMensagemErro("MEU TITULO | ERRO", error);
    });


var exibirModalHtml = function (config, callback) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: !0,
        templateUrl: 'app/modulos/modal/views/modal-html.html'
        controller:"ModalHtmlController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        size: config.size || "md"
        backdrop: 'static',
        resolve: {
            data: function () {
                return {
                    "vm": config.vm,
                    "header": config.header,
                    "html": config.html,
                    "buttons": config.buttons || [],
                    "callback": callback
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return modalInstance.result;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tenta limpar o cache, rodar o gulp de novo e refazer o teste.

Answer (score 0):

O erro pode estar na URL na qual o AngularJS está procurando, verifique a mesma da seguinte forma
[image: Verifique a URL]

Copie a URL que está tentando requisitar, se der 404 muito provável que o erro está no

`templateUrl: 'app/modulos/modal/views/modal-html.html'`